# Произношение аббревиатур в русском языке

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно произносятся аббревиатуры?

Comment: Если нет конкретики, то лучше в пособиях почитать.

Answer (score 1):

Аббревиатуры разные бывают, по-разному и произносятся. В основном придерживаются слогового принципа, там где можно, а там, где слог не получается из-за скопления согласных - по названиям букв.
Но есть много случаев, когда вместо правильного названия букв используются некие "просторечные" варианты: США: Сэ-шэ-а (вместо сша/эсша).

Это далеко не все, только наиболее частые ситуации. Есть достаточно подробный список произносительных норм, но он очень длинный и не для первого знакомства.

Лучше смотреть в словари.

Если дадите примеры, разберем.

Answer (score -2):

Всё об аббревиатурах читайте в статье из Письмовника  (Грамота.ру)

[**Как правильно употреблять аббревиатуры?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/60-rubric-91) (статья ***КЛИКАБЕЛЬНА*** - по просьбе слабовидящих).

Несколько частных случаев:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Всё об аббревиатурах читайте в статье из Письмовника*  Боже... Одно радует, что это "всё". ))) А остальное где? И на кой фиг картинки-то из текста делать? Вы хоть понимаете, что поисковики их не ловят?!

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте текст в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображений.

Comment: Ники, я не умею обыгрывать текст шрифтами и цветами; кому нужен полный текст статьи, зайдёт по кликабельной ссылке.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к пожеланию видеть текст, а "не игру с цветами". И  поближе к сути, желательно. У вас из пяти скринов три вообще "до кучи".

Comment: *кому нужен полный текст статьи, зайдёт по кликабельной ссылке* - некорректная постановка. "Кому нужен" найдет и без вашей "помощи". А вот система индексации ваш ответ не увидит вовсе. По-моему это очевидно.

Comment: Так я автору вопроса помогаю ответом, а не системе индексации.